# Get data from JSON based upon the input received

Tags: javascript, json

I need to fetch data based upon the input received.

For example, if the input is 'Royal python', I should get details of Royal python.but with the following code, i get error saying 'The file you asked for does not exist'. But I get the value into fname. But not sure if the function is correct to fetch data from from array.Also I wanted to know if there is any shorter way to do this. Please help?

I'm using JavaScript for this, my code and the web page look are below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>  

<form> <input type="text" name="fname" required> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button> `enter code here`
</form>  
<p id="demo"></p>  
<script> var text = '{"animals":[' + 
'{"Common Name":"Royal Python","Order":"Squamata","Family":"Boidae","Genus":"Python","Species":"regius","Zoo":"Blackpool Zoo","Number":4 },' + 
'{"Common Name":"Emperor Penguin","Order":"Sphenisciformes","Family":"Spheniscidae","Genus":"Aptenodytes","Species":"forsteri",`   "Zoo":"Welsh Mountain Zoo","Number":35 },' +` 
'{"Common Name":"Chimpanzee","Order":"Primates","Family":"Pongidae","Genus":"Pan","Species":"troglodytes",    "Zoo":"Blackpool Zoo","Number":8 }]}';  

obj = JSON.parse(text);  


//function to fetch data based on input

function myFunction(fname) 
{ var ani = ""; 
if (document.getElementByname("fname")="Royal Python")   
var ani =  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.animals[0].Zoo + " " + obj.animals[0].Species; }}  </body> </html>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question. It's good you showed us some code; this helps us to better understand the problem you're facing. As it is, however, it's not quite clear what the problem is. I suggest you [edit] your question, to tell us what isn't working in your code. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Now I have edited the question for more understanding.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues in your code:

`document.getElementByname("fname")="Royal Python"` should be `document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value == "Royal Python"`

Also, it's cumbersome to write the text string and then parse it as JSON. Just use a JavaScript object.

You're also making it difficult on yourself when trying to determine the animal. Use [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) if your browser supports it.

Here's a working example:

```js
var obj = {animals:[{CommonName:"Royal Python",Order:"Squamata",Family:"Boidae",Genus:"Python",Species:"regius",Zoo:"Blackpool Zoo",Number:4 }, {CommonName:"Emperor Penguin",Order:"Sphenisciformes",Family:"Spheniscidae",Genus:"Aptenodytes",Species:"forsteri",Zoo:"Welsh Mountain Zoo",Number:35 }, {CommonName:"Chimpanzee",Order:"Primates",Family:"Pongidae",Genus:"Pan",Species:"troglodytes",    Zoo:"Blackpool Zoo",Number:8 }]};

//function to fetch data based on input
function myFunction() { 
  var name = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value;
  var index = obj.animals.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.CommonName === name;
  });
  if (index >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.animals[index].Zoo + " " + obj.animals[index].Species;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" required value="Royal Python"> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your problem that uses a `for` loop to check each index of the animal array for a match. This match will be case-insensitive also.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input type="text" name="fname" required>
    <button onclick="fetchAnimal()">OK</button> `enter code here`
    <script>
    var animalsArr = [{
        "commonName": "Royal Python",
        "order": "Squamata",
        "family": "Boidae",
        "genus": "Python",
        "species": "regius",
        "zoo": "Blackpool Zoo",
        "number": 4
    }, {
        "commonName": "Emperor Penguin",
        "order": "Sphenisciformes",
        "family": "Spheniscidae",
        "genus": "Aptenodytes",
        "species": "forsteri",
        "zoo": "Welsh Mountain Zoo",
        "number": 35
    }, {
        "commonName": "Chimpanzee",
        "order": "Primates",
        "family": "Pongidae",
        "genus": "Pan",
        "species": "troglodytes",
        "zoo": "Blackpool Zoo",
        "number": 8
    }]

    function fetchAnimal() {
        var i;
        var len = animalsArr.length;
      
        // convert input name to lower-case
        var name = document.getElementsByName('fname')[0].value.toLowerCase();

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            // check to see if lower-case input is the same as lower-case animal name (this ensures the match is case-insensitive)
            if (animalsArr[i].commonName.toLowerCase() === name) {
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = animalsArr[i].zoo + ' ' + animalsArr[i].species;
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note**: It is highly recommended move the JS code into an external script file if you intend to add more interactivity to the page.

Comment: @sandy if this answer helped you, you should accept it